# Reference issue with android HelloGridView tutorial

Tags: java, android, oop, gridview

The classes `GridView` and `BaseAdapter` class can not be resolved.

I added `import android.widget.gridview`, as well as `import android.widget.baseadapter`. But now `setAdapter()` is becoming not valid, and neither is `setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener)`.

Should I create a public class `ImageAdapter` in its own `ImageAdapter.java` file?

I believe the tutorials did not explain all the stuff clearly.

Comment: here is the link of the tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

Comment: You better put the whole code you wrote. Sometimes you might be importing something with the same name, but a different import.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorials suppose you already know some Java, and your environment is setup properly. If you cannot resolve your imports, it's not a Android issue, but your Eclipse/SDK setup that you should check.

You also definitely should create one file per public class.